# creating gmail account using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

Not able to Select the month for Date of Birth.

Code I am using is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id = 'BirthMonth']/div")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000);     
WebElement months = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='BirthMonth']/div[2]/div[@id=':1']"));

Thread.sleep(2000);

months.click();
```

I also tried with by using DropDownList case. But Not able to set any Month.

Please Say me the Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyboard event replace mouse.

```
WebElement birthMonth = driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth"));
birthMonth.click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sendKeys` directly:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).sendKeys("July");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this up in a function

```
public void selectBirthMonth(int monthIndex)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#BirthMonth > div")).click();
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#BirthMonth > div.goog-menu > div.goog-menuitem")).get(monthIndex - 1).click();
}
```

and then call it like

```
selectBirthMonth(9); // 1 = January
```

Comment: Sorry Jeff , but with this also not able to select month. did it worked for you??

Comment: Same thing happening with Gender Selection.

Comment: Yes, the code worked for me. I ran it several times successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement month = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"BirthMonth\"]/div[1]"));
month.click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
//wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//fetch months from the dropdown and store it in a list
List<WebElement> month_dropdown = wd.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id=\"BirthMonth\"]/div[2]/div/div"));
    //iterate the list and get the expected month
    for (WebElement month_ele:month_dropdown){
    String expected_month = month_ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    // Break the loop if match found
    if(expected_month.equalsIgnoreCase("August")){
        month_ele.click();
        break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not drop down value , you have to click on drop down arrows and then click on any value which you have to pass from script.

Code is below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/software and tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();


//FirefoxDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp");   
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':7']/div")).click();
```

it is workable code for Birthmonth

Please find below link for same type of Question

> [Not able to select the value from drop down list by using Select method in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538290/not-able-to-select-the-value-from-drop-down-list-by-using-select-method-in-selen/45586739#45586739)