# Not able to select the value from drop down list by using Select method in Selenium

Tags: list, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I not able to select the options from dropdown list by using 'Select' method.

Here is my gmail account creation code.

```
enter code here

package samples;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class SmallFunctionalities {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp");   
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Select sitem= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")));
        sitem.selectByIndex(5);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }

}
```

### **Error Message**

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"**

---

Comment: Like the error mentions the element with the id 'BirthMonth' is a span. For the Select class to work the element you are providing its constructor needs to be of the 'select' html tag. You are not dealing with a 'pure' dropdown but one probably created with a combination of css and javascript. You will need to click to open it and then manually choose the option.

Answer (score 0):

It is not drop down value , you have to click on drop down arrows and then click on any value which you have to pass from script.

Code is below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/software and tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp");   
Thread.sleep(5000);

//Click on up/down arrow
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]/div[2]")).click();

// Now select value from list
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':7']/div")).click();
```

Comment: if you find answer is satisfactory and working. Please click on up-vote